# Validate form from angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a form as an angular 1.5 component. After this i want to reuse the component in different places (even twice on the same page) .

My problem is how to validate the form in the component . I tried to add a name for the form, but from what i've been able to see, using the same name in the same html page generates problems.

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Mgo1OvnonU5OOsrNGxy?p=preview)

```
ng-click="myFormName.$valid && viewModel.doSomething()"
```

---

i will rephrase my question and i changed my plunker to display my entire app and what i want to achieve. [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Mgo1OvnonU5OOsrNGxy?p=preview) .

The individual inputs are components that can be required or not (see customInput from plunker) . 
These components are used in a generic panel. (see customPanel from plunker) .

You can see in the panel two actions :

1) a submit button - in case a required elements is not filled, the browser will display something to tell the user what has to be filled

2) a picture with an action - my question is : How can i perform something similar with the submit action ? I want to have the same user experience (the browser displays me something to inform the user what has to be filled) or something that marks that the panel is not correctly filled

Comment: You should not have same form name twice in the same page. Instead of defining `<form>...</form>` your template, use it outside the template so that you can set your required form name. You template will contain the code which is there inside the `<form>` tags.

Comment: But then the whole idea of reusable component is not anymore there.

Comment: All the html code inside your `<form>` tag will be reusable right? But I don't know if there is any solution for this. Lets wait for other folks in SO to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Components have isolated scopes, so if you place a form in a component, the form controller will be attached to the isolated scope - which means you CAN use "multiple" forms with the same name (because each form is on it's own scope).

To get the form controller, simply bind to it in the component controller.

```
angular.module('test').component('myComponent', {
 template: '<div class="panel-group">' + 
        '  <div class="panel panel-primary">' +
        '   <form name="myFormName" ng-submit="viewModel.doSomething()" ng-cloak> ' + 
        '       <input type="text" required />  ' +
        '       <button type="button" ng-click="myFormName.$valid && viewModel.doSomething()">Another submit action </button>' +
        '       <button type="submit">Submit Me ! </button>' +
        '       current value = {{viewModel.count}} '+
        '   </form>' +
        '  </div> ' + 
        '</div>',

bindings: {
    formCtrl: '='
},

controllerAs : 'viewModel',

controller : function(){

  var model = this;
  model.formCtrl = model.myFormName; // This will bind your inner form controller to the outside binding property
  model.count = 0;

  model.doSomething = function(){
    model.count = model.count + 1;
  }

}
```

});

Now you can access the form controller from the outside scope, by binding to the "formCtrl" binding property.

```
<my-component form-ctrl="yourControllerBindingGoesHere"></my-component>
```

Comment: i rephrased my question (edited the initial post) and updated also the plunker. I want to achieve the same user experience for both actions from plunker (submit button and image click)